# Visualizing a decision tree from a sklearn random forest regressor

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

hi I have a random forest called `rf`.

The [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html) , tells me that `rf.estimators` gives a list of the trees. I am interested in visualizing one, or if I can't at least find out how many nodes the tree has.

my intuition was that the plot_tree function, shown [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html) would be able to be used on the tree, but when i run

`rf.estimators_[0].plot_tree()`

I get

`AttributeError: 'DecisionTreeRegressor' object has no attribute 'plot_tree'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import `tree` from Sklearn and pass the desired estimator to the `plot_tree` function.

Setup:

```py
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
X, y = make_regression(n_features=4, n_informative=2,
                       random_state=0, shuffle=False)
regr = RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=2, random_state=0)
regr.fit(X, y)

print(regr.predict([[0, 0, 0, 0]]))
#[-8.32987858]
```

Use [`plot_tree`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.plot_tree.html)

```py
from sklearn import tree
tree.plot_tree(regr.estimators_[0])
```

[image]